# Retrieve SQLite result as ndarray

Tags: python, sqlite

I am retrieving a set of latitude and longitudinal points from an sqlite database as this:

```
cur = con.execute("SELECT DISTINCT latitude, longitude FROM MessageType1 WHERE latitude>{bottomlat} AND latitude<={toplat} AND longitude>{bottomlong} AND longitude<={toplong}".format(bottomlat = bottomlat, toplat = toplat,  bottomlong = bottomlong, toplong = toplong))
```

However, as I am supposed to make a ConvexHull (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull) which has an `ndarray` as input, I need to save the results for cur as a ndarray. How would I do that?

Right now I fetch the values as :

```
    positions = [[floats(x[0]) floats(x[1])]  for x in cur]
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert positions to an ndarray. `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` can accept a list of lists as well:

```
import scipy.spatial as spatial
hull = spatial.ConvexHull(positions)
```

---

Also, if your `MessageType1` table has latitude, longitude fields of type float, then you should not need to call `float` explicitly. Instead of

```
positions = [[floats(x[0]) floats(x[1])]  for x in cur]
```

you could use

```
positions = cur.fetchall()
```

Note that if you are using NumPy slicing syntax, such as `positions[:, 0]`,
then you would need to convert the list of lists/tuples to a NumPy array:

```
positions = np.array(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

When following http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple` when plotting my hull, if it is tuples.

Comment: Yes, you could get that error if you try using NumPy slicing syntax on `positions` when `positions` is not a NumPy array. To make `positions` a NumPy array, simply poss the list of tuples to `np.array`.